Why does $\textbf{tr}(F_{i}(\nabla\,\text{log}\,\text{det}(F))) = \textbf{tr}(F_{i}F^{-1})$?
In Example A.3 of Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe, they write that $$\textbf{tr}(F_{i}(\nabla\,\text{log}\,\text{det}(F))) = \textbf{tr}(F_{i}F^{-1})$$
where $F \in R^{\,p,p}$ is positive definite, $F_{i}  \in R^{\,p,p}$ is symmetric.
How does the equality hold?
I know the gradient outputs a p-by-p matrix consisting of the partial derivative of $\text{log}\,\text{det}(F)$ w.r.t matrix elements at $F$, and $\textbf{tr}(AB)$ is just the sum of the element-wise multiplication of $A$ and $B$. But why does $\nabla\,\text{log}\,\text{det}(F) = F^{-1}$? (Or is that not what is happening here?)

Have you tried diagonalizing $F$?

@J.G. Oh right! Thank you, I appreciate the hint. It looks trivial now..

@Tim: I’d sure like to see the details.

Right, I will write an answer as verification.

The book contains a derivation of the gradient of log set in the appendix on vector calculus.  The derivation is two or three pages long.

@BrianBorchers May be me being tired but I can't seem to find it though. May I ask where is it in the appendix?

So after carefully thinking this through, I haven't get everything laid out. I know changing the basis does not change the determinant, but what about the gradient? How does it not affect it?
Umm, in fact, how should I interpret the $\nabla$ here?

It's on pages 641-642, starting at about the middle of page 641.

@BrianBorchers Ahhh I was just reading it the other day. How did I not recall it. Thank you.

Still, I would like to know how to improve my answer, if possible. I didn't take into account the $\nabla$ when changing basis, now I am not sure how to think about it.
The book took a first-order approximation approach to reach the conclusion tho.

// Note this is NOT a complete answer
Since $F\in R^{\,p,p}$ is positive-definite, there exists a basis of $R^{p}$ such that F is diagonal, with only positive numbers $a_{1},...,a_{p}$ on the diagonal.
And since changing basis does not change the determinant(but what about $\nabla$?), we have $\text{det}F = a_{1}*...*a_{p}$
Thus $\text{log}\,\text{det}(F) = \text{log}\,a_{1}+...+\text{log}\,a_{p}$
The output matrix of the gradient is zero for non-diagonal element, since $\text{log}\,\text{det}(F) = \text{log}\,a_{1}+...+\text{log}\,a_{p}$ does not contain non-diagonal term. For diagonal element $a_{i}$, the output element in the matrix is $$\frac{\partial\,\text{log}\,\text{det}(F)}{\partial a_{i}}= \frac{1}{a_{i}}$$ (log base is assumed to be e?)
Thus $\nabla\text{log}\,\text{det}(F)=F^{-1}$
